# Spring MVC - REST Api, keep getting 400 Bad Request when trying to POST

Tags: spring, rest

i have a REST api service which should receive POST calls.

I'm using POSTMAN to test them, but i keep getting a 400 Bad Request Error, with no body, maybe i'm building bad my controller...

This is the controller

```
@PostMapping("/object/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteObject(@RequestBody long objectId) {
        logger.debug("controller hit");
        Object o = service.findByObjectId(objectId);
        if(o!=null){

        service.deleteObject(object);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
                   }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    }
```

Using `@RequestBody` i should send the request in JSON, in this way:

```
{
"objectId":100
}
```

But i get a 400 error, and the strange think is that my logger `logger.debug("controller hit");` it's not printed in logs...

Comment: Check you content-type header is "application/json" or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending `{ "objectId":100 }` would result in receiving an object X with an `objectId` attribute in your java method.

If you just need to send an id, you can use `@PathVariable`

```
@PostMapping("/object/{id}/delete")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteObject(@PathVariable("id") long objectId) {
```

Also, consider using [`DeleteMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/DeleteMapping.html) instead of `PostMapping` to delete an object.